# Is there any way to tell aptana to use more than just one ftp connection?

Tags: ftp, aptana, transfer

I hope you know what I am meaning.
If I synchronise (or just download) BIG projects over ftp, this will be heavy time expensive. 
So, is it possible that apatana studio handle ftp transfers over more than just one active connection?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a ticket opened on the request: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-729.